# Why does chaining a createTextNode in an element's appendChild returns the text node?

Tags: javascript, dom

let me explain:

```js
var m = document.createElement('table').createTHead().appendChild(document.createElement('th').appendChild(document.createTextNode('hello')));
```

I am trying to create a table element, then create a head element and inside a th with 'hello' as the text. But this function returns the text value.

I am not sure what my mistake is.

EDIT:
Solution provided.

Comment: It seems to log the last thing you added to your element tree. If you console.log `a.parentNode.parentNode` you'll see it's the last node under the `table` you created.

Comment: And why does that happen in javascript? it seems awkward, in other cases a node is returned

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems like the problem was that the last node is what being returned therefore theres a getter function ".getRootNode()" which solves this issue.